# matching rows between tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr, row, matching

I've got 2 tibbles with an index column and n variables that have the same names across the 2 tbs:

```
index   var_1   var_2   ...     var_n
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

For each row in tb1, there is exactly one row in tb2 that has matching values for var_1 until var_n. My goal is to **find the index values of those matching rows in tb2** for each of the rows in tb1.

The difficulty is that no assumption can be made about the number of variables in the tibbles or the names of those (except for `index`), only that the names are the same between the tibbles.

**Example data**

```
library(tidyverse)
(tb1 <- tibble(index = sample(1:5), alpha = c("A","A","A","B","B"), 
                  bravo = c(1,2,3,1,1), charlie = c("x","x","x","x","y")))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  index alpha bravo charlie 
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     2 A         1 x    
2     5 A         2 x    
3     4 A         3 x    
4     3 B         1 x    
5     1 B         1 y  

(tb2 <- tibble(index = c(10, 6, 9, 7, 8), alpha = c("A","A","A","B","B"), 
               bravo = c(1,3,2,1,1), charlie = c("x","x","x","x","y")))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  index alpha bravo charlie 
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1    10 A         1 x    
2     6 A         3 x    
3     9 A         2 x    
4     7 B         1 x    
5     8 B         1 y
```

**Expected output**

```
10, 9, 6, 7, 8
```

Can somebody give a (preferably tidyverse) solution to this problem?

Comment: `semi_join(tb2, tb1[-1])`, though it won't reorder observations for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `inner_join` by all non-index columns -

```
inner_join(select(tb1, -index), tb2) %>% 
  pull(index)

[1] 10  9  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `base`

```
merge(tb1, tb2, by = intersect(names(tb1), names(tb2))[-1])$index.y
```

Comment: Here's a simpler version - `merge(tb1[-1], tb2)$index`. `by` arg defaults to common columns.